# How to open non-HTTP links with webbrowser in Python?

Tags: python, html, browser

I have a 2-dimensional array from a program I made in Python 2.7. I wanted to be able to better visualize this and make sure everything is right by making a table out of it, somehow.

I'm relatively new to Python (read: learned it last year), and rather than trying to mess with `.len()` and adding spaces, I remembered [an article I read on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5980134/turn-any-browser-window-into-a-quick-edit-notepad) a while ago on how to make a quick-edit notepad in a modern browser. (tl;dr: `data:text/html, <html contenteditable>` makes a blank canvas for text in your browser.)

I thought I might be able to do the `data:text/html` thing and just use HTML `<table>` elements to create a table, but when I try to use `webbrowser.open()` to actually get it open in Chrome, it just pops up the annoying Windows 8 dialog "No apps are installed to open this type of link (data). Look for an app in the Store?"

So how can I get `webbrowser.open()` to force Chrome so that it doesn't leave it up to Windows to decide which application to open the link with?

Comment: what link are you trying to open?

Comment: @elf Something like `data:text/html, <html><table border><tr><td>Example</td><td>Table</td></tr></table>`, but with the data I want. Just paste that into your browser's address bar.

Comment: Weird. FWIW, that data URI with the table works fine for me in Firefox 29.0.1 on Linux. Chrome should be able to handle data URIs, but maybe that's a Windows "security feature"...

Comment: I suggest writing your HTML table to a file (as proper HTML with a `doctype` and opening & closing `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags) and then open that file with `webbrowser.open()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can save your html to '.html' file and open it using standard shell command. Thre is a **windows** version:

```
import os
def printarray(arr,filename="array.html"):
    content = getcontent(arr)
    file = open(filename,"w")
    file.write(content)
    file.close()
    os.startfile(filename)#windows only

def getcontent(arr):
    #override with actual code
    return "<html><table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr><tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr></table></html>"
```